# Как правильно спарсить? python bs4 requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, bs4

появился вопрос как спарсить от сюда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

именно div с классом image, так как при

`soup.find('div', class_='more-images').find('div', class_='image')`

парситься и первый и второй div.

Comment: soup.find('div', class_='more-images').findAll('div', class_='image')[1]

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!